# Copyrights are still visible when MAP_TYPE is set to None

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Even that the issue is fixed and closed, I still see the Google Copyright at the bottom left when setting the `MAP_TYPE` to `MAP_TYPE_NONE`.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4834

Im using the latest google_play_services_lib (version 9)

Comment: But is Google Play services up to date on your device? What device/google play version do you have?